# Converting HJD to JD in Python

Tags: python, astropy

I'm currently working on period analysis of a variable star, where I have a long csv file consisting of many measurements of the magnitude of the star at a given time. For the program I'm using, I need the time to be in JD, however my file measures the time in HJD. Is there any relatively straightforward way to convert JD to HJD in python? I heard that there is an astropy module that will do the conversion for you, however I'm having trouble figuring out what to do. I came across astropy.time, and cant figure out how exactly it performs the conversion.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PyAstronomy` in python:

```
from PyAstronomy import pyas

jd = 2440000.0
print("HJD (ra=100 deg, dec=37 deg): ", pyas.helio_jd(jd-2.4e6, 100.0, 37.0))
```

Output:

```
HJD (ra=100 deg, dec=37 deg):  39999.99536863883
```

Comment: from PyAstronomy import pyasl